# Apply an overlay layer to a single layer, and then adjust the result of that?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs5, overlay

So I just purchased the CS5.5 Master Collection, I'm an enthusiast :)  I have a question pertaining to blending layers and applying adjustments in Photoshop.  How do I apply an adjustment layer to a blended layer, while only having the blended layer affecting one layer beneath it, and then having the adjustment layer apply only to the result of that created by the blending?  I know it's a mouthful...

I have three layers, from top to bottom: adjustment layer, blending layer, artwork layer.  I have applied a gradient to the blending layer using the Vivid Light option, which in turn affects all the layers below it (I only want it to affect the artwork layer though).  I then want to apply an adjustment to the resulting effect.

Apologies if I was vague, but my terminology on the subject matter is not yet up to par as I'm a complete newbie to this field.  Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Cheers,
Les

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is a lot easier than the problem defined. Just hold the ALT key, then move your mouse cursor **between** those two layers (blending layer and the artwork layer). The cursor will change to this strange arrow, then CLICK.

The blending layer will then be applied only to the artwork layer beneath it and your problem is solved!